# Reading data with hibernate does not synchronize with the database

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions, hibernate-session, hibernate-cache

I am using hibernate to interact with the database. Insert, delete, update operations there is no problem because of they are ended by a commit statements **session.getTransaction.commit()**.

But While `selecting data,listing records` hibernate return data displayed previously and all new records or update made are not displayed.

So before asking this question I tried(two weeks ago)  to navigate to similar questions but I did not find the  answer while applying all recommendations.

> (A) Enabling second level cache (b) Increase Isolation level

This became strange for me because when I want to update recently inserted record  I get the following.

```
HTTP Status 500 - No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bd.model.TestType#15]

type Exception report
message No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bd.model.TestType#15]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.bd.model.TestType#15]
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$1.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:377)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:79)
    org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:68)
    org.hibernate.Hibernate.initialize(Hibernate.java:306)
    com.bnr.clinic.services.TestTypeServices.getTestTypeById(TestTypeServices.java:79)
    com.bnr.clinic.controller.TestTypeUpdateController.doPost(TestTypeUpdateController.java:85)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)

note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 logs.
```

Here is a method of selection I am using!

```
public TestType getTestTypeById(int idTestType) {
    session = sf.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    session.clear();
    TestType testTypes = (TestType) session.load(TestType.class, idTestType);
    Hibernate.initialize(testTypes);
   return testTypes;
}
```

My hibernate configuration file is this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
    <hibernate-configuration>
        <session-factory>
<!-- Database connectivity -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mis</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">@ict#</property>
            <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->

            <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
            <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>

<!-- Disabling timeout -->
            <property name="connection.autoReconnect"> true</property>
            <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
            <property name="c3p0.min_size">5</property>
            <property name="c3p0.max_size">20</property>
            <property name="c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
            <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
            <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
            <property name="connection.release_mode">auto</property>

            <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->

            <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
    
            <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
            <property name="show_sql">true</property>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
            <mapping class="com.bd.model.Test" />
            <mapping class="com.bd.model.TestType" />
            
             
        </session-factory>
    </hibernate-configuration>
```

So  I am pleased to ask two questions:

> Is there any thing wrong with my method or Am i wrong with my hibernate configuration?
>
> What is preventing hibernate to synchronize with the database to get new inserted records?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that every transaction started, must be committed to ensure that hibernate is synchronizing with the database. Hibernate use caching if these READING( SELECT) transactions are not committed and you continue to get the same records by the time there are new records loaded into the database.

My configuration is fine the only changes were on behalf of service methods

```
public TestType getTestTypeById(int idTestType) {
    Session session = sf.openSession(); // sf as a sessionFactory instance
    Transaction tx = null;
    TestType testType = null;
    try {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        testType = (TestType) session.get(TestType.class, idTestType);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        if (tx != null)
            tx.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return testType;
}
```